# Errors in my test score program?

Tags: c#

So I am making a program that you enter in 2 test scores and it says in a label if test 1 or test 2 has the higher grade and the letter grade of both tests. This should be an easy program but I am getting an 2 errors: **Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?).** I am getting this error for letterGrade1 and letterGrade2. Here is the code:

```
    private object TestScores(decimal Test)
    {
        string testGrade = null;

        //Perform the function
        if (Test >= 90) {
            testGrade = "A";
        } else if (Test >= 80) {
            testGrade = "B";
        } else if (Test >= 70) {
            testGrade = "C";
        } else if (Test >= 60) {
            testGrade = "D";
        } else if (Test < 60) {
            testGrade = "F";
        }


        //return the answer
        return testGrade;
    }


        }
    }
```

If anyone could please help me solve the problem I would greatly appreciate it!

Problem has been solved! Thanks to everyone.

Comment: In your TestScore Method you should change the return type from object to string since that is the only type you are returning. Otherwise when you receive that value back you would have to place a cast in front of that method (string)TestScores(test1ScoreDecimal);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this...

```
 private string TestScores(decimal Test)
    {
        string testGrade = null;

        //Perform the function
        if (Test >= 90) {
            testGrade = "A";
        } else if (Test >= 80) {
            testGrade = "B";
        } else if (Test >= 70) {
            testGrade = "C";
        } else if (Test >= 60) {
            testGrade = "D";
        } else if (Test < 60) {
            testGrade = "F";
        }
        //return the answer
        return testGrade;
    }
```

There's no reason to return an object if the consumer needs to down cast it.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign an object to string in these lines of code:

```
    letterGrade1 = TestScores(test1ScoreDecimal);
    letterGrade2 = TestScores(test2ScoreDecimal);
```

you can solve it in two ways either change the return type of TestScores to string.
or cast the result to string explicitly.

```
    letterGrade1 = (string)TestScores(test1ScoreDecimal);
    letterGrade2 = (string)TestScores(test2ScoreDecimal);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign the result of `TestScores` to a `string` variable, but `TestScores` returns an `object`...

Change the return type of `TestScores` to `string`

or change to `TestScores(test1ScoreDecimal).ToString()` if you really need to return `object` for some unknown reason

Answer (score 0):

Either change the return type of `TestScores` to `string` or use:

```
letterGrade1 = (string)TestScores(test1ScoreDecimal);
```

Answer (score -1):

Either make TestScore a static class with no constructor :

```
static class TestScores
{
   static string Calculate(double score){}
}
```

Or instantiate the class properly:

```
letterGrade1 = new TestScores(test1ScoreDecimal);
letterGrade2 = new TestScores(test2ScoreDecimal);
```

Comment: Disregard...On second glance I see TestScores is not a class. I thought it was at first.

Comment: Does this make any sense? You have a static class (where the OP had a method) that has no constructor, yet you are trying to instantiate a new instance of it?, and you are not even using the calculate method you seem to have thrown in that has no method body?